# cannot show right time axis in machine start and stop stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use highchats to show some machines' start and stop chart.

for example, give a time range 2016-05-01 00:00:00 to 2016-05-07 23:59:59, we will find:

machine A start at 2016-05-01 00:10:00, then stop at 2016-05-05 10:22:00, then start at 2016-05-06 11:23:00

machine B start at 2016-05-01 02:18:00, then stop at 2016-05-04 20:22:00, then start at 2016-05-07 11:23:00

machine C start at 2016-05-01 03:10:00, then stop at 2016-05-03 21:22:00, then start at 2016-05-05 11:23:00

the time axis always start at 1970-01-01, after set min: 1451577600000,//2016-01-01 00:00:00

the start point is right, but other points is wrong.

following is my code, anyone can help me?

Thanks.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Machine Start and Stop</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    -->
    <script src="http://www.highcharts.com/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width;400px;height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
    $(function () {
                // Stacked bar chart
                var chartype = {
                    type: 'bar'
                }
                var chartitle = {
                    text: 'Machine Start and Stop Record'
                }
                var chartAxisX = {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Machines'
                    },
                    categories: ['MachineA', 'MachineB', 'MachineC']
                }
                //time format：http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php
                var chartAxisY = {                
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats:{
                        minute: '%H:%M',
                        hour: '%H:%M',
                        day: '%Y-%m-%d',
                        month: '%Y-%m',
                        year: '%Y'
                    },
                    startOnTick:true,
                    //endOnTick:true,
                    //pointStart: 1451577600000,//1451577600000=2016-01-01 00:00:00
                    min: 1451577600000,//2016-01-01 00:00:00
                    title: {
                        text: 'Date time'
                    }
                }
                var chartlegend = {
                    reversed: true
                }
                var chartplotoptions = {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'//stacking: 'percent'//
                    }
                }
                //    -28800000=1970-01-01 00:00:00
                //1451577600000=2016-01-01 00:00:00
                //1462032029000=2016-05-01 00:00:29
                //1462635223000=2016-05-07 23:33:43
                //1477384800000=2016-10-25 16:40:00
                //var timeDiff=8*3600*1000;
                var chartSeries = [{
                    name: 'Start',
                    color: '#4ba31e',
                    //data: [1, 2, 3]
                    data: [1462032000000, 1462032029000, 1462035029000]
                }, {
                    name: 'Stop',
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    //data: [4, 5, 6]
                    data: [1462432029000, 1462432529000, 1462439029000]
                }, {
                    name: 'Start',
                    color: '#4ba31e',
                    //data: [7, 8, 9]
                    data: [1462635223000, 1462635223000, 1462635223000]
                }]

                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: chartype,
                    title: chartitle,
                    xAxis: chartAxisX,
                    yAxis: chartAxisY,
                    legend: chartlegend,
                    plotOptions: chartplotoptions,
                    series: chartSeries,
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                });
            });
    </script>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inverted columnrange chart.

```
var chartype = {
                type: 'columnrange',
                inverted: true
            }
```

Setting a machine's data would look like this:

```
{
                name: 'MachineA',
                data: [{
                x: 0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 1, 0, 10),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 5, 10, 22),
                color: 'green'
              }, {
                x: 0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 5, 10, 22),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 6, 11, 23),
                color: 'red'
              }, {
                x: 0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 6, 11, 23),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 8),
                color: 'green'
              }]
            },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/2792/

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

find this demo, but it just can show one status.

```
[daily activities chart][1]


  http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/2034/
```